# How to get the simple product of the configurable product from Order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, configurable-product

I'am using Magento 1.9. I have to make return process in magento.

For that I'm listing all items of order. But for the configurable product I need to take the ID of the simple product to make the return request, since I need to process the return request for corresponding simple product.

Using the below code all the configurable items. But I could not get the actual simple product related with that item.

```
foreach ($orderItems as $item){

if ($item->getParentItemId())
   continue;
   $productId = $item->getProductId(); //It gives only the configurable product Id
if ( $item->getProductType() == 'configurable' ) {
    $productId = $item->getOptionByCode('simple_product')->getProduct()->getId(); // It is not working
            }
    }
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$OrderNumber = "100000201";//Put your order Number here

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber, 'increment_id');

$order->getAllVisibleItems();


$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
    ->load();

foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {

    //Ignore conf for now
    //Alt. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE = 'simple';
    if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
    {



        echo "\n*********************************\nMage Order #: ".$OrderNumber."<br/>";
        //Simple Item Info from Order
        echo "Type: ".$sItem->getProductType()."<br/>";
        echo "Order Id: ".$sItem->getOrderId()."<br/>";
        echo "Product Id: ".$sItem->getProductId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Id: ".$sItem->getId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Name: ".$sItem->getName()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Sku: ".$sItem->getSku()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Price: ".$sItem->getPrice()."<br/>";

        $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();
        echo "Parent Item Id: ".$pItemId."<br/>";

        echo "<br/>*****<br/>";
        //Get Parent Item Information
        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId"); //use an item_id here

        //Testing, want to see whats inside the parent/configurable item?
        //print_r($item->toArray());

        echo "Parent Type: ".$item->getProductType()."<br/>";
        echo "Parent Order Id: ".$item->getOrderId()."<br/>";
        echo "Product Id: ".$item->getProductId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Id: ".$item->getId()."<br/>";
        echo "Parent Item Price: ".$item->getPrice()."<br/>";
        echo "Qty: ".$qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered())."<br/>";

        //get Active Product Data
        $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
        $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();
        echo "new Product UPC:".$nUpc = $nProduct->getUpc() . "<br/>";
        echo "new Product Price:".$nPrice = $nProduct->getPrice(). "<br/>";

        }
    }
```